# run sql command through BASH

Tags: bash

Interactively, I use the following command to start a program that allows me to enter sql queries:

```
./nco_sql -server AGG_P -user root -password ''
```

Then I am manually entering the below command

```
select count(*) from alerts.status;
```

I want a script through which i don't need to enter the sql command manually.

**NOTE**  I don't have permission to edit the `nco_sql` script I need to write a separate script in which I am running the `nco_sql` script.

Comment: You could try `./nco_sql -server AGG_P -user root -password '' <<< "select count(*) from alerts.status;"`

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you need is to have the script find your query on STDIN.  So

```
echo "select count(*) from alerts.status;" | ./nco_sql -server AGG_P -user root -password ''
```

seems like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with nco_sql, but this is how i run queries using sqlplus in bash so i would think it would work the same with your tool

```
./nco_sql -server AGG_P -user root -password '' <<EOC
    select * from dual;
EOC
```

it's pretty similar to janos suggestion but i find it to give a cleaner code if you have a few lines to send as they are defined in between the two EOC tag (which could be anything else that make sense for you).

Comment: nco_sql is just a script to connect with the db, thanks for your help i will try your suggestion.